# Can two independent bootstrap servers subscribe to the same Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm getting messages from an unknown origin in a Kafka topic in my dev environment and it's screwing things up. I'm guessing that our configuration is to blame but I'm not sure.

At work we've share the same topic name and consumer group IDs across different environments, so that in prod we have bootstrap server aws.our-prod.com, and in dev we have aws.our-dev.com. So basically two unconnected domains.

I didn't set this up, but the duplicate topic/group naming across environments seems awfully suspicious to me.

I think this is the problem. Is my hunch correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the title of your question is related to the problem you're asking about. Particularly, "bootstrap servers" are not the thing that subscribes. If you have data from an unknown location, then you ought to enforce certificate management and ACLs that limit producers to certain apps (especially critical prod topics)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check zookeeper nodes of both environment Kafka nodes. Make sure they different.
2. Check you DNS mapping/host mapping, Both domain names can be mapped to same IP address. (If you run locally, check etc/hosts file)

Those scenarios can be happen and there can be more. But same topic is not shared with different environment clusters for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Different consumers may be listen to Group id that is used by your project. Or other projects may be send message to your topic.

Answer (score 0):

Basics:

1. Donot use same kafka cluster for PROD & DEV environment
2. if still want to use same kafka cluster, then at-least use different groupid or topic name on PROD & DEV respectively

**RESOLVING CURRENT ISSUE**

PROD Environment

- Consumers: change topic from 't1' to 't2', groupid can be same.
- Producers: change topic from 't1' to 't2'.

**Result:** unknown producer will keep sending to old topic 't1'

If still not resolved, then there is problem with current set of producers.

Answer (score 0):

No, duplicate properties are not an issue, in itself

For example, in a Spring app, you'd define defaults at the top level

application.properties

```
topic=t 
consumerGroup=g
```

And override profile/environment properties

application-dev.properties

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=dev-cluster:9092
```

application-prod.properties

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=prod-cluster:9092
```

And this is very common, and nothing wrong with it.

It's *possible* you've got a producer *somewhere* in your environment that has misconfigured (or altogether missing) the production config file, and has decided to fallback into the dev properties or defined their dev bootstrap servers in the non-environment specific config, but as a consumer or the Kafka administrator, there's no way you'd know that.

Assuming you are able to consume the messages, and the producer has code in source control, you can look for trails there, but otherwise, you're effectively left looking for active network connections to the broker at the TCP level and doing packet analysis